# Long press in Webview - App Crash

Tags: android, select, webview, crash

When i long press text in the Webview (android), the app crashes. I also can't select text, because it crashes before the text is highlighted. Normally, the app would show the default Contextual Action Bar, but the app crashes.

In my Activity OnCreate, i used "setWebViewClient" and "LoadURL".

The webview is inside a RelativeLayout (main), below another RelativeLayout;

Here is the Log:

> 09-15 23:35:21.680 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro is waiting
>   for the debugger on port 8100...
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.681 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.771 26033-26043/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/art﹕
>   Debugger is active
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.910 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.910 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.111 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.312 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.512 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.714 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.915 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.116 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.318 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1383)
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.868 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual
>   native library version number ""
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.869 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging
>   enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.952 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.958 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.991 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   E/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.057 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/Adreno-EGL﹕ : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:
>   AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU
>   () OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08 Build Date:
>   03/07/14 Fri Local Branch: Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
>   Local Patches: NONE Reconstruct Branch:
>   AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 + NOTHING
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.104 26033-26228/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Thread[16,tid=26228,Native,Thread*=0x48f0c758,peer=0x6526f030,"Thread-40584"]
>   attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.127 26033-26223/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Thread[17,tid=26223,Native,Thread*=0x48ce1740,peer=0x6526ff90,"Thread-40585"]
>   attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.202 26033-26228/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled
>   because there is no system implementation
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.250 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.340 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.406 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:25.074 26033-26277/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Thread[19,tid=26277,Native,Thread*=0x48ed9778,peer=0x652b6480,"Thread-40588"]
>   attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:25.223 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ ==> onReceive: s=0, m=0, n=h2w, sb=true
>
> 09-15 23:35:25.226 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ reportUpdate: state=0, devices=[Speakerphone,
>   Headset earpiece]
>
> 09-15 23:35:26.116 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>
> 09-15 23:35:26.291 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 52 frames! The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.
>
> 09-15 23:35:26.325 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
>
> 09-15 23:35:27.031 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
>
> 09-15 23:35:27.143 26033-26312/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕
>   Thread[22,tid=26312,Native,Thread*=0x48f02c50,peer=0x652d35f8,"Thread-40591"]
>   attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.842 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   android.app.ActionBar.getThemedContext()' on a null object reference
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.852 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:302)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.855 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.859 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getActionBarThemedContext(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:210)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.863 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:195)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.868 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:359)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.872 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2437)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.876 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2362)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.879 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.883 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.886 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.890 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4554)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.894 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.showSelectActionBar(ContentViewCore.java:2341)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.898 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.access$2200(ContentViewCore.java:93)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.902 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore$13.showHandles(ContentViewCore.java:2154)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.906 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectionHandleController.onSelectionChanged(SelectionHandleController.java:168)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.910 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.onSelectionBoundsChanged(ContentViewCore.java:2620)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.914 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native
>   Method)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.918 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.921 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.925 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.928 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5088)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.931 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.935 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.938 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>
> 09-15 23:35:37.040 26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro A/libc﹕
>   Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000065b1 (code=-6), thread 26033
>   (digimecum.dgpro)

Comment: can you please post the code

Comment: Java Code? The code is very large... is there any problems to post a large code?

Comment: @GabrielAngst: See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Strip down the code as far as you can while still reproducing the error, then post that stripped-down code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the code, I found that the problem was in the beginning of the Java file. It started with

```
package com.edireito.dgpro.dgpro;
import...
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

And when I changed "ActionBarActivity"  to "Activity", it worked!

Thanks.

Comment: Hm... your problem was that you tried to call a method on your Actionbar, but your Actionbar was null! So you decided to get rid of the Actionbar at all instead of solving the NPE. This answer won't really help anyone.